# XML Schema 1.0 - qualified versus unqualified: what specifically changes in a valid instance?

Tags: validation, xsd, xml-namespaces

Say I have a valid XML instance file ("1") that contains only elements in the `targetNamespace` of its schema (Schema "A"). The instance is valid per this schema. Instance 1 has the correct namespace declaration for its schema on its (1's) root node, and nowhere else.

Now I take the same instance 1 and try to validate it against Schema "B".

B is identical to A except I changed `elementFormDefault="unqualified"` to `elementFormDefault="qualified"`.

I am seeing 1 failing to validate against B. Why? What do I need to change in 1 (producing instance "2") to make it valid again against B?

Is the "qualified" flavor of an XML schema just for instances with an explicit namespace prefix on every single element?

---

Example schemas: All based on a minimal XML structure for communicating some data structures like `file/record/info1`. Unfortunately these seem to behave differently again from my real-world examples (which are too big to post here).

A: UNqualified schema

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- The UNqualified version -->
<xs:schema elementFormDefault="unqualified" targetNamespace="http://example.com/xsd-prefixes-test"
  xmlns:test="http://example.com/xsd-prefixes-test" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="file">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" ref="test:record" />
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="record">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="test:info1" />
        <xs:element ref="test:info2" />
      </xs:sequence>
      <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:integer" use="required" />
      <xs:attribute name="status" type="xs:NCName" use="required" />
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="info1">
    <xs:complexType />
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="info2">
    <xs:complexType />
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

B: QUALIFIED schema

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- The QUALIFIED version -->
<xs:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://example.com/xsd-prefixes-test"
  xmlns:test="http://example.com/xsd-prefixes-test" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="file">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" ref="test:record" />
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="record">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="test:info1" />
        <xs:element ref="test:info2" />
      </xs:sequence>
      <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:integer" use="required" />
      <xs:attribute name="status" type="xs:NCName" use="required" />
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="info1">
    <xs:complexType />
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="info2">
    <xs:complexType />
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

---

Example schema instances:

*Instance 1 - prefixes for the targetNamespace on all elements; validates against both schemas*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- ALL prefixes -->
<test:file xmlns:test="http://example.com/xsd-prefixes-test"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://example.com/xsd-prefixes-test xsd-prefixes-test_qualified.xsd">
    <!-- validates against xsd-prefixes-test_UNqualified.xsd AND xsd-prefixes-test_qualified.xsd -->
    <test:record id="1" status="ok">
        <test:info1 />
        <test:info2 />
        <!-- etc... -->
    </test:record>
    <test:record id="1" status="ok">
        <test:info1 />
        <test:info2 />
        <!-- etc... -->
    </test:record>
    <test:record id="1" status="duplicate_deprecated">
        <test:info1 />
        <test:info2 />
        <!-- etc... -->
    </test:record>
</test:file>
```

Instance 2: - no namespace prefixes anywhere but still validates against A and B!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- NO prefixes anywhere -->
<file xmlns="http://example.com/xsd-prefixes-test" xmlns:test="http://example.com/xsd-prefixes-test"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://example.com/xsd-prefixes-test xsd-prefixes-test_qualified.xsd">
    <!-- validates against BOTH xsd-prefixes-test_UNqualified.xsd AND xsd-prefixes-test_qualified.xsd -->
    <record id="1" status="ok">
        <info1 />
        <info2 />
        <!-- etc... -->
    </record>
    <record id="1" status="ok">
        <info1 />
        <info2 />
        <!-- etc... -->
    </record>
    <record id="1" status="duplicate_deprecated">
        <info1 />
        <info2 />
        <!-- etc... -->
    </record>
</file>
```

Instance 3 - does not validate against either A or B - why not?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- NO prefixes anywhere -->
<test:file xmlns:test="http://example.com/xsd-prefixes-test"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://example.com/xsd-prefixes-test xsd-prefixes-test_qualified.xsd">
    <!-- validates against NEITHER xsd-prefixes-test_UNqualified.xsd NOR xsd-prefixes-test_qualified.xsd -->
    <record id="1" status="ok">
        <info1 />
        <info2 />
        <!-- etc... -->
    </record>
    <record id="1" status="ok">
        <info1 />
        <info2 />
        <!-- etc... -->
    </record>
    <record id="1" status="duplicate_deprecated">
        <info1 />
        <info2 />
        <!-- etc... -->
    </record>
</test:file>
```

---

Error messages (same with both schemas A and B):

- Instance 3 - cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'record'. One of '{"http://example.com/xsd-prefixes-test":record}' is expected.

---

I am seeing this error or very similar with instance files along the pattern of both 1 and 2, when used with the schema of the "opposite" flavor (an instance with prefixes against a schema with unqualified).

Conversely I am seeing instances of style 3 that do validate against the qualified type schema.

- Is there a dependency on what language/parser/validation engine is used?

Comment: Please post a [mcve] that illustrates your problem, including XML, XSD, and the exact error message you receive.  Thanks.

Comment: OK, I have tried to be both comprehensive and concise. I ended up finding further questions because this seems to be a counterexample; and I don't understand why. But I hope the underlying question is clear (what must change in an instance to keep the instance valid when you change `elementFormDefault="unqualified" ` to `elementFormDefault="qualified" ` ?

Comment: OK, I just compared the original "unqualified" version of my xsd with the updated "qualified" version. This is definitely the only change found in a 2-way diff using oxygen XML editor. Why is it a breaking change for some instances?